# c2.js scatterplot does not use new x-axis values

Tags: javascript, scatter-plot, c3.js

Please forgive me if this question has an obvious answer.

I am using c3.js to plot two sets of data on the same graph. The data happen to be a time series. I make the first plot (c3.generate) and it looks fine.

In the second part, however, it seems as if c3.load completely ignores the x-axis data and plots the y-values at the same x-values as the previous plot.

So that I could see what was going on, I did this after a timeout to give a pause between the two plots.

At first I thought that this might have to do with my time representation, but I get the same results whether or not I used the Linux epoch time or a time string.  You can see this by uncommenting the string version of timeStamp and timeStamp2 and commenting out the Linux epoch.

My guess is that I am misunderstanding how the load method works in scatter plots, but any additional insight would be appreciated.

Thanks,

Paul

```
***
  <!-- read in scripts in javascript -->
  <script src="c3/c3.min.js"></script>
  <script src="d3/d3.min.js"></script>
  <script>
    /*
     The goal is to draw/redraw the same timeSeries graph 2 times:
      First: with one set of data, which increases linearly in time
      Second: adding a second set of data, which is offset in time from the first, 
              but also increases linearly
    */

    //fill array with data
    timeStamp = ["timeStamp",
         "2020-04-14 12:00:00", 
         "2020-04-14 13:00:00", 
         "2020-04-14 14:00:00", 
         "2020-04-14 15:00:00", 
         "2020-04-14 16:00:00", 
         "2020-04-14 17:00:00", 
         "2020-04-14 18:00:00", 
         "2020-04-14 19:00:00", 
         "2020-04-14 20:00:00"
        ];
    
    /*
     timeStamp = ["timeStamp",
         1586887200000,
         1586890800000,
         1586894400000,
         1586898000000,
         1586901600000,
         1586905200000,
         1586908800000,
         1586912400000
        ];
    */
    yValue = ["yValue", 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9];
    //load new data into chart  
    
    //declare and draw first chart
    var yValueChart = c3.generate({
    bindto: '#yValue',
    axis: {
        x : {
        type: 'timeseries',
        tick: { format: '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M'}
        }
    },
    data: {
        x : 'timeStamp',
        xFormat : '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S',
        columns: [timeStamp,
              yValue
             ],
        type : 'scatter'
    }
    });
    
    //wait a bit more and draw second chart
    setTimeout(function() {
    //fill array with data
    
    timeStamp2 = ["timeStamp2",
             "2020-04-14 12:30:00", 
             "2020-04-14 13:30:00", 
             "2020-04-14 14:30:00", 
             "2020-04-14 15:30:00", 
             "2020-04-14 16:30:00", 
             "2020-04-14 17:30:00", 
             "2020-04-14 18:30:00", 
             "2020-04-14 19:30:00", 
             "2020-04-14 20:30:00"
             ];
    /*
     timeStamp2 = ["timeStamp2",
             1586889000000,
         1586892600000,
         1586896200000,
         1586899800000,
         1586903400000,
         1586907000000,
         1586910600000,
         1586914200000
        ];
    */
    yValue = ["yValue2", 1.2, 2.2, 3.2, 4.2, 5.2, 6.2, 7.2, 8.2, 9.2];
    //load new data into chart
    yValueChart.load({
        xs : {
        yValue2 : 'timeStamp2'
        }, 
        columns: [
        timeStamp2,
        yValue
        ]
    });
    //why is timeStamp2 ignored?
    }, 3000);
  </script>
***
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem was that I was not specifying the parameters correctly in the call to c3.generate.  The correct code there is

...

```
var chart = c3.generate({
bindto: '#yValue',
axis : {
        x: {
    type : 'timeseries',
    tick : { format: '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M' }
        }
},
data: {
        xs: {
    yValue: 'timeStamp'
        },
        // iris data from R
        columns: [
    timeStamp,
    yValue 
        ],
        type: 'scatter'
}
});
```

...

The main difference is the addition of the

...

```
xs : {
yValue : 'timeStamp'
}
```

...

Paul